# A problematic output from a For loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

```
rho<-rep(0,4)
for(i in 1:4){
  p=rep(0,4)
  cval=rep(0,times =4)
  for(j in 1:4){
    if(mean(k[j,])==pool[i])
      for (l in 1:4){
        rho[l]=.5*(ran[i,2])+((.75)^.5)*rnorm(1,0,1)
        if(rho[l]<0)
          p[l]=k[j,l]*.6
      }
    cval[j]=sum(p)
  }
  CVAL=sum(cval)}
```

In the code above I have a 4x4 matrix called `k`. I also have a 4x2 matrix called `ran`. `pool` is a randomly sorted vector with entries matching the averages of the rows of `k`.

No matter what random numbers are generated the `cval` output is always `(0,0,b,b)` where `b` represents a random number. I believe this should not be the case. Does someone see an error in my code that would cause this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What language is this? Please edit your question and tag it appropriately. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like R. OP, please tag this question with the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Please post the data as well, and then we have a chance of figuring out what you are doing. Not before.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond to this in time, I got help from a friend in person and it is now solved.  Thanks for the offered help though!

Comment: Then post a solution and mark it as correct. SO does not exist purely for your purposes. Or delete the post. Your choice.